# The Android Manifest.xml is getting corrupted

Tags: android, debugging, android-manifest, corruption, parsing-error

I have encountered an un-debug-able problem for my last three projects.
The same error I get after creating every two-three activities in each project is :-

```
Parser Exception :  The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well formed.
```

This error comes in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

I'm using ADT Eclipse provided by Google for the purpose.

Is this error debuggable or I have to just delete the project and start overall again till the error comes again?

Comment: Post your manifest file contents.

Answer (score 1):

```
package="com.example.sqlitenew"

android:versionCode="1"

android:versionName="1.0" >


<uses-sdk

    android:minSdkVersion="8"

    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />


<application

    android:allowBackup="true"

    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"

    android:label="@string/app_name"

    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity

        android:name="com.example.sqlitenew.MainActivity"

        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: this is not an valid XML markup. consider removing or editing it

Answer (score 0):

Every tags in XML must inside a root tag and all tags must be closed perfectly. Otherwise it throws the error: The error **Parser Exception :  The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well formed** states that the element inside the root tag is not closed properly.

Your XML should be in the format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <application>
        <!-- activities declaration -->
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: <<<<<<Original     is the first line of Android Manifest.xml . The error shows up in it...

Comment: @TyrangeDenhops don't add it in comment. update your question by adding it

Answer (score 0):

Are you interchanging the project files between two operating systems? The same error came for me when I was working on linux and my project partner on windows.
Try to do `ctrl+shift+F` in the XML file. it worked for me.